# Displaying a Wygwam field in a SAEF/Channel_Form entry

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, wygwam, channel-form, saef

I finally have a project to use SAEF/Channel Forms in and I am banging my head against the wall trying to display the wygwam fields. Does anyone know the trick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to type `{field:wygwam_field_name}` within the `{exp:channel:form}` tag pair.

Comment: I couldn't add all that I needed in a comment, so see the answer below for the details...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add all this in a comment:

Thanks Brandon. I see in the console that the field is attempting to populate, but I have the following errors in the console log:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://itnqa.com/docs/config.js?t=D7GG".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < config.js:1
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://itnqa.com/docs/skins/wygwam3/editor.css?t=D7GG".
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://itnqa.com/docs/lang/en.js?t=D7GG".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < en.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://itnqa.com/docs/styles.js?t=D7GG".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < styles.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://itnqa.com/docs/plugins/stylesheetparser/plugin.js?t=D7GG".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < plugin.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icons' of null

*** ADDING CODE ***
I am using the following to open a colorBox popup to host the edit template:

```
{if logged_in}
    <div class="gallery">
        <a class="button green" href="{site_url}includes/edit/{url_title}" title="Editing ITN# {title}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> &nbsp;Click to Edit</a>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Then in my template for edit, I have this:

```
{exp:channel:form 
    channel="doc" 
    id="publishForm"
    return="docs/{last_segment}" 
    url_title="{last_segment}"
}
    <label for="title">ITN Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100" onKeyUp="liveUrlTitle();">

    <input type="text" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75" size="50" style="display: none;">

    <label for="itn_title">ITN Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="itn_title" id="itn_title" value="{itn_title}" size="50" maxlength="750">

    {label:symptoms}
    {field:symptoms}

    {label:cause}
    {field:cause}

    {label:resolution}
    {field:resolution}

    <input class="button green" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

*** ADDED ***
This is on IIS you mentioned htaccess, but with this site I have to use web.config. I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{R:1}" negate="true" pattern="^(pdfs|css|js|swf|skins|plugins|images|tools|themes|admin|index\.php)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Looks like that's due to some kind of crazy .htaccess redirect on your end. If I try accessing http://itnqa.com/docs/skins/wygwam3/editor.css?t=D7GG directly, I'm redirected to http://localhost/docs/skins/wygwam3/editor.css?t=D7GG .

Comment: The site is behind a firewall. Not accessible by anyone outside their company. Sorry, I can't change that part.

Comment: Where should those go to? I get directed to a template when I click on them instead of the CSS or JS.

To elaborate, docs is my default template group for this site. I am in a 'doc' when editing the Channel Form.

Comment: Those URLs should be pointing to /themes/third_party/wygwam/...  They get generated based on your “URL to your 'themes' folder” setting in Admin > General Configuration.

Comment: I thought so. Here are my settings...
http://mktrsc.alamode.com/3rr0r$/genConfig.png
   I don't know why those would be off. Could it be because I am passing the entry to an edit Channel_Form that is held in a colorBox popup?.....see other "answer"

Comment: just keep seeing these:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < config.js?t=D7GG:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < lang/en.js?t=D7GG:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < styles.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://itnqa.com/docs/plugins/stylesheetparser/plugin.js?t=D7GG".

Comment: also if I change out the paths manually, I get a 404...

http://itnqa.com/themes/third_party/wygwam/config.js?t=D7GG

Comment: I'm not sure why they're 404ing, but that has nothing to do with EE or Wygwam -- those should just be standard Apache requests that go straight to the file and return it. Maybe your .htaccess file is getting in the way, or maybe the files don't exist to begin with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10735/discussion-between-brandon-kelly-and-brian-mallett)

Comment: Brandon - Thanks for all the help. It ended up being a colorbox conflict with pulling in the CSS for some reason. I was able to create a flat page and edit fine. I ended up rebuilding things to use a jquery dialog to edit in place.